# Filter 8 days ago

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau work sheet with a Measure called 'Cost' and a Dimension called 'Created_date'.

On Sheet 1, I have the 'Cost' filtered by 'Yesterday' which is an option in the filter.

I would like to have a second sheet which is filtered 8 days ago, so the same time the previous week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a calculated field using datemath to return a boolean testing if day of created_date = 8 days ago:

   datediff('day',[Created_Date],today())=8
2. Drag this calculation to the filters shelf and filter on "True"